# How to make dynamic bit width integers in C?

Tags: c, arbitrary-precision, extint

I want to represent extended integers and came across `_BitInt()` but it doesn't work dynamically.
I'm trying to do something like this:

```
void fun(int n)
{
    _BitInt(n)* val = malloc(n); //doesn't work
}
```

I understand that everything stored on the stack needs to have its size known at compile time, but I'm `malloc`ing here so I don't understand why this doesn't work

Comment: Where did you come across `_BitInt()`?  It isn't a standard feature AFAIK.

Comment: Why are you using a compiler-specific extension like `_BitInt`? Why not attempt to find a portable library to solve whatever problem you need solving? And what is the problem you need solving? I mean, why are you using `_BitInt` to begin with?

Comment: Since _BitInt(32) is a certain type, and types are a compile-time thing, this certainly wouldn't work. You can write your own library for n-bit integers, or use a library like GMP which does it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler it's expected to be a [new type in C23](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C2x) but obviously it's fixed-width, not arbitrary-precision and can't be dynamically resized at run time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, `_BitInt(N)` isn't a standard C type. It's a Clang extension and proposed for the next C23 standard. And `_BitInt(N)` isn't an extended integer type either but a ***fixed-width*** integer type. The [C standard proposal](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2709.pdf) also says clearly

> The original proposal was to name the feature `_ExtInt` and refer to it in standards text as a “special extended integer type”. However, during committee discussion, the feature was changed to be called a “bit-precise integer type” and so the name `_ExtInt` was a misnomer.

Being a fixed-width compile time type, the `N` is part of the type itself (like in C++ templates) and not some variable that modifies the type at run time. Therefore the type `BitInt(n)` can't be constructed. That also means `_BitInt` isn't suitable for [arbitrary-precision math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) (dynamic bit width integers in your words)

The fact that you allocated memory dynamically has nothing to do with the type. `malloc(n)` just allocates a memory region of `n` bytes and doesn't know about what you're going to store in that region. And you're also doing it wrong, n bytes of memory can store `_BitInt(n * CHAR_BIT)` and *not* `_BitInt(n)`

Comment: for future readers: `_BitInt(N)` **is a standard type**, introduced in C23. also a nitpick, but `_BitInt` was never a Clang extension, but rather `_ExtInt` was.